# Where can I find documentation on the "before-parameter-build" event prefix used when registering event handlers with Boto3?

Tags: boto3

I have very limited Python experience and am trying to understand an AWS Lambda Function written in Python in an existing project.  The code is registering event handler functions using `<aws-service>.meta.events.register('before-parameter-build.*', <handler-function>)`.

I'm trying to read about the Boto3 event system from the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/events.html), but I can't find any references to this particular `before-parameter-build` event type.  Where can I find some documentation about this event type, please?  Thanks!